# Protractor test:IE11 giving error as : Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: protractor, internet-explorer-11, webdriver-manager

I am running an automation suite in cross browser. The entire suite is working good in chrome, Firefox and edge and giving timeout error in error in IE11 as ::

"Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL"

where as my default timeout in jasmine and allscripttimeout set as 90000.

Please help me regarding that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question so that it becomes clear what exactly you did. A nice guideline is https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For testing purpose, try to increase the time for timeout to see whether it helps to solve the issue for IE. It can be possible that IE is taking more time for processing than other browsers. If possible for you than please try to provide any sample example which we can try to refer to narrow down the issue.